# HP 10 GB adapter in ubuntu 18.04 - HP 652503-B21

Tags: ethernet

I have ubuntu 18.04 on both machines and I connect them with trhough SFP via a DAC cable recommended by HP using 2 same model HP 10GB adapters (HP 652503-B21). I cannot find any drivers for these. I tried the driver ubuntu provided, then I tried HP driver for red hat by converting it to debian package by "alien". I have tried every which way, but when I look at the network panel it says "cable unplugged" for both machines. Anybody have a solution to the problem or point to a place where there is a driver (HP does not provide debian drivers)?

Comment: What kind of computer? SFPs are usually for connecting enterprise grade networking equipment, not just random computers

Comment: I have an HP precision tower server with Intel processor (one of those xeons with 6 cores) and the mother board that comes out of the box with Ubuntu installed. The other is a custom one I pulled together with Asus Motherboard with threadripper (2950X), again with Ubuntu installed. They are really desktop computers not servers. I use them to process data and I want them to be able to connect faster with SFPs. I have a copper SFP cable about a meter long and 2 of these HP 10G ethernet cards.

Comment: I'd imagine the root problem is that the Ubuntu drive will not work with Red Hat. Converting applications may work in some cases, but hardware communication instructions found in drivers are unlikely to translate simply by changing the package type.

Comment: I imagine, I am more on the software side and inexperienced when it comes to hardware that is usually not found in desktops. It is a learning experience and an opportunity to improve though. Thank you for the answer.